# Subquery returned more than 1 value.. query C# exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i made a simple query joining two tables in the database using inner join. the query is given as follows:

```
Select t1.UserName,t1.Title,t1.FirstName,t1.LastName,t1.MiddleName,t1.IsActive,t1.ProgramID,t2.Email
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId
```

the query executes well in SQL Server Management Studio and returns rows as needed but while debugging my code in Visual Studio, when it reaches at

```
adapter.fill(dataset);
```

it throws the following exception:

**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

here is the C# code snippet:

```
string selectCmd = @"Select t1.UserName,t1.Title,t1.FirstName,t1.LastName,t1.MiddleName,t1.IsActive,t1.ProgramID,t2.Email
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId ";
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConnString))
                   {
                       SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                       adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectCmd, conn);
                       conn.Open();
                       adapter.Fill(dataset);
                   }
```

Any suggestions please?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your C# side code, which calls this query and fills the dataset?

Comment: Select TOP 1 can't be used as the query is supposed to fetch all the rows that meet the join's condition.

Comment: i am gonna post it..@PM

Comment: have you seen this post? http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/978185-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value.html

Comment: Is this a dynamic query, from what you have here it looks like you are using ado.net. but I do not see a sub query unless this is the sub query. it would be good to see the C# code and the main query. but it looks like your users have more then 1 email

Comment: i have edited the question to include the C# code and in table2 every 'UserId' is having a single email address.

Comment: There are no sub-queries.

Comment: what seems strange to me is the fact that Query runs successfully in SQL Server Management Studio and return rows as expected but in C# code while filling data set it gives this exception

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider - This appears like you are looking at the wrong section of code. Are you sure the exception is coming from THIS adapter.Fill() statement?

Comment: Yes, i debugged it @ StingyJack

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider - Do you have any DataRelations setup in the dataset? Also, put this code into a small console app and see if it fails there.

Comment: I don't see how this query can be throwing this exception.  It has no subqueries in it.  Try to run a trace on the SQL Server and look at the activity around this query.

Comment: Did you run profiler to see if the query you think is being sent is waht is actually being sent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subquery returned more than 1 value in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757405/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Your join returning more than one value and you're trying to put these values in a single parameter..

Example: ----It's your error query

```
     DECLARE @Test INT 
SET @Test = (SELECT ID FROM ABC A INNER JOIN XYZ X ON A.ID = X.AID)
```

Solution:

```
     DECLARE @Test INT 
   SET @Test = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ABC A INNER JOIN XYZ X ON A.ID = X.AID)
```

Comment: Where do you see this in the question?

Comment: are you sure, You are giving the solution of above question?

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, this query is supposed to fetch all the rows matching the join's condition not just the TOP 1, So this is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys it was a timer job issue. one has to restart the sharepoint timer service before deploying the solution.